# How can I copy the entire row using App Scrpts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet on Google Sheets with two tabs (Tab1 and Tab2).

Aba1 has several lines.

How can I copy the entire row of the cell that is selected in Tab1 to the second row of Tab2?

I would like an App Scripts script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getActiveRange().getValues();
const sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tab2');
sheetTo.getRange(2, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Reference:

[getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)